# The time in 'Fahrenheit 451'

Tags: ray-bradbury, fahrenheit-451

Sorry for making a duplicate thread. This was discussed around two years ago and I think we all agreed that the year was 2053. But recently I came across [an article](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/~/media/a3f8c7a36b9e4f62bf44fd00ebec3d43.ashx?la=en) which states the setting is in 24th century and that this was [mentioned somewhere in the beginning of the novel](http://www.gradesaver.com/fahrenheit-451/q-and-a/24th-century--485) which I personally do not remember but still, probably I missed something. So my question is, is the time in 'Fahrenheit 451' the year 2053 or it is 24th century or it is something else?

Comment: yes..but I wasn't sure it was ok to ask questions in old threat so I created a new one

Comment: besides that question was answered two years ago..since then some new discoveries could have been made

Comment: @ClaireWilson - Welcome to the site!  This may have worked being posted as a new answer to the old question since you're showing the sources you have; I think that would have been perfectly fine.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to post to the older thread.